# Manage Different Screen Resolution and Density in Android

Tags: android-layout

I have developed one application that works well in most of the devices but if run this application in HTC Sensation 4G(Resolution: 540x960, Density: 255), layout looks very small.

I am using **android qualifiers** for managing layouts.
Firstly I used below qualifiers but i didn't get any result.

drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi for Drawables.
layout-large, layout-medium, layout-small for Layout.

And now I am using following qualifiers and it looks quite good but not up to the best level,

drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi for Drawables.
layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi for Layout.

Has anybody developed any application for this device? How do I manage layout for this device?